# Visual Fox Pro Word Automation

Tags: vba, ms-word, visual-foxpro

```
LOCAL oWord, oDocument, oRange, Lc_start, Lc_expr, Lc_ris, Ln_count, Lc_val
DIMENSION Lc_funct[1]

Lc_expr = ""
Ln_count = 1

oWord = CREATEOBJECT("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = .T.
cFile = GETFILE()

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(m.cFile)

oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
    nWordCount = oRange.Words.Count
    oRange.Collapse(1)
    FOR nWord = 1 TO m.nWordCount-1
    oRange.Expand(2)
    cWord = oRange.Text
    DO CASE

    CASE m.cWord = "<|<"
        Lc_start = .T.
        Lc_Expr = ""

    CASE m.cWord = ">|>"
        Lc_start = .F.
        Lc_funct[Ln_count] = Lc_Expr
        Ln_count = Ln_count + 1
        DIMENSION Lc_funct[Ln_count]

    CASE m.Lc_start
        Lc_expr = Lc_expr + m.cWord

    OTHERWISE
        *don't do anything

    ENDCASE

    oRange.Collapse(0)
    ENDFOR


    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
    oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = Lc_funct[i]
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = EVALUATE(Lc_funct[i])
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR

    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
    oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = "<|<"
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = ""
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR

    FOR i = 1 TO Ln_count-1
        oRange = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range()
        oRange.Find.Text = ">|>"
        oRange.Find.Replacement.Text = ""
        lFound = oRange.Find.Execute( , , , , , , , , , , 2 )
    ENDFOR
MESSAGEBOX("DONE")
```

Hello everyone. I wrote this code to automate Word from Visual Fox Pro. I put between the escapes "<|<" and ">|>" some VFP code(like take some values from tables and so on). At the press of a button, the code scans all the document and, when find these escapes, evaluates the istructions between. The last two FORs eliminate the escape strings.

The code works, but I ask. There is a better way to do what I look for?

Also, if I have a table, there is a way to decide BEFORE the automation which columns I want to pass inside the Word document?

Comment: Asking "is there a better way to code this" is not really on-topic on Stack Overflow - questions here should be about code that's *not working*. You might look at the guidelines for posting on the Code Review site and see if this isn't a better fit, there. Also, one issue per Question is the rule, here, since the site concept is Q&A - this isn't a discussion forum. The two questions you ask are not related to each other...

Comment: Sorry if I used the site in the wrong way, and thank you kindly for pointing me on the right site. Thank you again.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/220565/52915)